# How to do selection sort using 2 for loops using scanner? Read Details

Tags: for-loop, java.util.scanner, bubble-sort, selection-sort

this is how i do my bubble sort

```
 import java.util.*;
        class bubblesort
        {
            public static void calc()
            {
                int i , j,temp;
                int a[]=new int[10];
                Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
                for(i=0;i<10;i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter Numbers");
                    a[i]=sc.nextInt();
                }
                for(i=0;i<9;i++)
                {
                    for(j=0;j<9-i;j++)
                    {
                        if(a[j]>a[j+1])
                        {
                            temp=a[j];
                            a[j]=a[j+1];
                            a[j+1]=temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for(j=0;j<10;j++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Sorted array " +a[j]);
                }
            }
        }
```

I found many ways of doing selection sort as well but i am not being able to understand then. Can someone post the changes in bubble sort and selection sort with similar syntax , code and in scanner .

Answer (score 0):

this is the syntax i found to be extremely similar to the one given above..

```
import java.util.*;
class selctionsort
{
    public static void calc()
    {
        int i , j;
        int m;
        int n ;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter how many Numbers to be sorted");
        n=sc.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int [n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter The Numbers");
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for (j=i;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(a[i]>a[j])
                {
                    m=a[i];
                    a[i]=a[j];
                    a[j]=m;
                }
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorted array is " +a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: m is used as a temporary variable to store original value